# How to print multidimensional array in table?

Tags: php, html

I am having an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 7
        )

    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bear Delaware Operating � NM Emissions Report
            [1] => Bear Delaware Operating � NM Emissions Report
        )
)
```

But when i print this in table then it will be print like this:

```
foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $product) { 
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $i=0;
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $product[$i]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo product[$i]; ?></td>         
        </tr>
        $i++;    
    }
}
```

Result is:

```
ID                                                      NAME    
1Bear Delaware Operating � NM Emissions Report          2Bear Delaware Operating � NM Emissions Report
```

But i want my result like this

```
ID                                  NAME    
1                                   Bear Delaware Operating � NM Emissions Report
2                                   Bear Delaware Operating � NM Emissions Report
```

Comment: That's invalid PHP code. It would make your task a lot easier if you had a decently grouped array to begin with. Do you have control over how your first array is built? Why not group `id` and `name` together in its own array/object?

Comment: where is the id 2 ? there is only id 1 and 7

Comment: `foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $product)` makes little sense - the items under the keys `id` and `product` _are not_ (all of them) products. If you really need to work with such a less than optimal data structure, then loop over either the `id` or `product` sub-array, using the "extended" foreach syntax, that gives you access to the key as well. Use that key to address the corresponding value in the other sub-array.

Comment: Please always paste (relevant parts of) your real code, not a re-typed version which is full of basic syntax errors - it obscures the scenario and people will get distracted pointing out the basic issues instead of focusing on the real problem

Comment: Assuming your data has the same number of “rows” for each “column”, and assuming the sub-arrays are lists (zero-based, increasing by one), you can use something like this: https://3v4l.org/040us

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to use two foreach, you can solve it this way

```
<?php
$array = Array(
    'id' => Array(
        0 => 1,
        1 => 7
    ),
    'name' => Array(
        0 => 'Bear Delaware Operating � NM Emissions Report',
        1 => 'Bear Delaware Operating � NM Emissions Report2'
    )
);

$table = <<<TABLE
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
TABLE;

foreach ($array['id'] as $key => $value) {
    $table .= <<<TABLE
    <tr>
        <td>{$value}</td>
        <td>{$array['name'][$key]}</td>
      </tr>
TABLE;
}

$table .= <<<TABLE
    </table>
TABLE;

echo $table;
```